# JTextField alinhamento a esquerda, porem ele não se mantem a esquerda

Tags: java, swing

Estou trabalhando com JtextField e estou tendo um problema com alinhamento.

O tamanho do campo é padrao, não posso alterar. O campo tambem não é editavel, ele recebe o valor com base em um calculo entre quantidade e valor Unitário. Ele recebe um valor numerico muito grande, 15 digitos e realmente precisa ser deste tamanho para fins fiscais. o problema é que mesmo ele estando alinhado a Esquerda, quando ele recebe o numero, ele não mostra os numeros iniciais e sim os finais.. por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e ele deveria ficar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já utilizei o `setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);` e ele continua na mesma situação.

Alguem teria alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, essa posição não tem relação com o alinhamento do texto visto que seu texto é maior que o `JTextField`, mas sim pela posição do cursor.
Para que seja exibido o início do texto e não o fim como esta acontecendo, utilize:

```
jTextField.setCaretPosition(0);
```

**Importante**
Você deve utilizar o comando acima **depois** de setar o texto no JTextField, para que assim ele mova o cursor deste campo para a primeira posição.

Comment: Obrigado, eu estava usando esse caretPosition, porem ao criar o TextField e não quando ele é atualizado. Funcionou agora!